# wordpress admin plugin menu custom css

Tags: php, javascript, css, plugin-development

I have a plugin that has a top level menu and subsequent submenus. Each one of these pages are going to need their own css and javascript. My code at the moment is:

```
//main menu
add_menu_page( "My Business", "My Business", "contributor", "fbusiness", array($fmb_admin, "get_page"));
//sub menus
add_submenu_page("fatemagic-business", "Products", "Products", "contributor", "fbusiness-product", array($fmb_product, "get_page"));
```

What I need is for custom css and scripts for the page that is displayed when the submenu is clicked. I did do this before but have just spent 3hrs trying to find it online and can't. If my memory is correct it looked something like:

```
$page = add_submenu_page("fatemagic-business", "Products", "Products", "contributor", "fbusiness-product", array($fmb_product, "get_page"));
print_admin_script($page, "http://location/to/javascript");
print_admin_style($page, "http://location/to/css");
```

Maybe this technique is deprecated? It was about 3 or 4 years ago when I used this technique.

cheers ;)

Comment: ... found it. arrgggh, sorry for wasting time. Will put up the answer in 5 mins. (knew i'd find it as soon as i asked a question, lol) ans: add_action('admin_print_styles-' . $page, 'func_to_enqueue_script') - will put up detailed answer in about 5 mins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the late reply on this but here is the answer. In order to have custom css for each of my sub-menu admin pages my code needs to be like this:

```
    //main menu
add_menu_page( "My Business", "My Business", "contributor", "site-business", array($fmb_admin, "get_page"));

//sub menus
$page = add_submenu_page("site-business", "Products", "Products", "contributor", "site-business-product", array($fmb_product, "get_page"));
add_action('admin_print_styles-' . $page, array($fmb_product, "load_styles"));
add_action('admin_print_scripts-' . $page, array($fmb_product, "load_scripts"));
```

hope this helps someone else ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use the `admin_head` hook and just echo out what you need to:

```
function my_admin_head() {
    // Custom Style
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="'.WP_PLUGIN_DIR.'/style.css" type="text/css" />';

    // Our JS
    echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>';

}
add_action('admin_head', 'my_admin_head');
```

Comment: unfortunately this will add the styles and scripts to all admin pages. But I finally found the answer - literally 2 search's after asking the question lol